# Will using Parallel.ForEach benefit in ObjectContext.Add

Tags: entity-framework-4, objectcontext, parallel.foreach

I am using Entity Framework with the generic repository pattern. I have used the following method to add an object.

```
public int Add<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class
{
   DataContext.AddObject(GetEntityName<TEntity>(), entity);
   return SaveChanges();
}
```

I am also thinking of extending this to support multiple entities.

```
public int Add<TEntity>(TEntity[] collection) where TEntity : class
{
   foreach (TEntity item in collection)
   {
     DataContext.AddObject(GetEntityName<TEntity>(), item);
   }

   return SaveChanges();
}
```

Will there be an actual benefit in using `Parallel.ForEach` instead of the `foreach` loop in the above scenario?

Also because I haven't called `SaveChanges()` until the end of the loop, if there is lets say a **primary key violation**, will it be thrown inside the loop or when `SaveChanges()` is called? Will I be able to rollback the changes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[ObjectContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.aspx) is not thread safe. Here's the remark on MSDN

> The ObjectContext class is not thread safe. The integrity of data
>   objects in an ObjectContext cannot be ensured in multithreaded
>   scenarios.

So better not use `Parallel.ForEach`.

Comment: You can use Parallel.ForEach if you're willing to lock all the accesses to the ObjectContext. If there's a fair bit of creation logic for each item being added, it could be worth it.